# How to use post from script?

Tags: html, forms, post

Ths script generates a number:

```
function updateDue() {
    var kmold1 = parseInt(<?php echo $km; ?>);
    var kmnew1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("kminput").value);
    var tot = kmnew1 - kmold1;

    document.getElementById("kmtot").innerHTML = tot;
    document.getElementById("kmnew").innerHTML = kmnew1;
    document.getElementById("kmold").innerHTML = kmold;
}
```

The number is displayed on a webpage with this code:

```
Diff in Km: <span name="kmtot" id="kmtot" value=""></span><br>
```

This is part of an form that is used to post to an other file.

How can I send the output of id="kmtot" to the next php file?
I have tried:

```
Diff in Km: <span name="kmtot" id="kmtot" value=""></span><br>
```

Not working.

```
<input type="hidden" name="kmtot" id="kmtot">
```

If I add this, the number of id="kmtot" is not displayed on the webpage, and is not transfered.
Any hints or solutions?

Comment: Why not using Ajax?

Comment: I am relatively new to programming. That's why.  Any links to how I can learn to do that?

Comment: Ok no problem, are you using jQuery?

Comment: Just make the input a type=text and set it as readonly.  You may also want to style it so it doesn't have a border around it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, use this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your-php-file.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    'kmtot': $('#kmtot').val(),
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

In *your-php-file.php*, `$_POST['kmtot']` will return the value of your element with the ID `kmtot`.

If you are not using jQuery, you could use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).